# Android application of maps.me API

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap

I want to Show the map on my app as offline so that am using the API name as Maps.me

On after using its API I got my app which displays the current city on clicking that particular city it downloads the map from net and show it in offline.

But my Query is on clicking the capital it just redirect from my app to mapsme app and showed the map but i want to show the map in my app.

How can i do it anyone have an idea share me.

Answer (score 0):

For that you may have to modify source code of maps.me. As natively maps.me does not support other apps. I also tried to figure out if we can use it but could not do it. So right now I am modifying Maps.me code and building a wrapper over it and integrate it in my app.